# Android KeyEvent.getCharacters() or keyEvent.characters is deprecated

Tags: android, keyevent

As per documentation from API 29, `KeyEvent.getCharacters()` is deprecated, but there is no alternative that I could find for same.

As per documentation it says `"@deprecated no longer used by the input system."` from API 29. What does this actually mean ?

Answer (score -1):

This constant was deprecated in API level 29.
No longer used by the input system. getAction() value: multiple duplicate key events have occurred in a row, or a complex string is being delivered. If the key code is not KEYCODE_UNKNOWN then the getRepeatCount() method returns the number of times the given key code should be executed. Otherwise, if the key code is KEYCODE_UNKNOWN, then this is a sequence of characters as returned by getCharacters().

no longer used by the input system. Please check more details here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getCharacters()